# Two different radio buttons in a foreach working as one

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this code with a 5 star rating(radio button) to be used in two different questions.

The problem is: the two ratings of each question are working as one. I mean, if I select something in the first question when I do a selection in the second question it unselect in the first one. It is working as a unique radio button.

How can I fix it? What am I missing?

```
           @foreach (var pergunta in Model.ls_pergunta)
            {
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label for="co_pergunta_avaliacao" class="control-label">@pergunta.tx_pergunta</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="estrelas" id="pergunta_@pergunta.co_pergunta">
                            @{
                                int i = 1;
                                foreach (var item in @pergunta.ls_opcoes)
                                {
                                    <label for="cm_star-@i"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                                        <input type="radio" id="cm_star-@i" name="pergunta_@pergunta.co_pergunta" value=@item.Value />
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```
.estrelas input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
.estrelas label i.fa:before {
  content:'\f005';
  color: #FC0;
  font-size:40px;
}
.estrelas input[type=radio]:checked ~ label i.fa:before {
  color: #CCC;
}
```

I followed the instructions that I received, but did not work. Below I post the View Source Code:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label for="co_pergunta_avaliacao" class="control-label">ASPECTOS FORMAIS/GRAMATICAIS</label>
                                                
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 estrelas" id="pergunta_1">
                        
                            <label for="cm_star-1"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                                <input type="radio" id="cm_star-1" name="pergunta_1" value=1_1 />
                            <label for="cm_star-2"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                                <input type="radio" id="cm_star-2" name="pergunta_1" value=1_2 />
                            <label for="cm_star-3"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                                <input type="radio" id="cm_star-3" name="pergunta_1" value=1_3 />
                            <label for="cm_star-4"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                                <input type="radio" id="cm_star-4" name="pergunta_1" value=1_4 />
                            <label for="cm_star-5"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                                <input type="radio" id="cm_star-5" name="pergunta_1" value=1_5 />
                                   </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label for="co_pergunta_avaliacao" class="control-label">CONTE&#218;DO/ARGUMENTA&#199;&#195;O</label>
          
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 estrelas" id="pergunta_2">
                        <label for="cm_star-1"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                                <input type="radio" id="cm_star-1" name="pergunta_2" value=2_1 />
                            <label for="cm_star-2"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                                <input type="radio" id="cm_star-2" name="pergunta_2" value=2_2 />
                            <label for="cm_star-3"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                                <input type="radio" id="cm_star-3" name="pergunta_2" value=2_3 />
                            <label for="cm_star-4"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                                <input type="radio" id="cm_star-4" name="pergunta_2" value=2_4 />
                            <label for="cm_star-5"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                                <input type="radio" id="cm_star-5" name="pergunta_2" value=2_5 />

                     </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML you create a group of related radio buttons by giving them all the same `name` attribute.

Demo:

```html
Group 1:
<input type="radio" name="group1" value=1 />1
<input type="radio" name="group1" value=2 />2
<input type="radio" name="group1" value=3 />3
<input type="radio" name="group1" value=4 />4
<br/>
Group 2:
<input type="radio" name="group2" value=1 />1
<input type="radio" name="group2" value=2 />2
<input type="radio" name="group2" value=3 />3
<input type="radio" name="group2" value=4 />4
```

Therefore in your case you're going to have to vary the `name="fb"`, changing it each time you're rendering a new question.

It also would make sense if the `name` matches the name of the field in the viewmodel that you want it to map to when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that. I made the changes in the name. Now I have name="pergunta_1" and name="pergunta_2" , but the problem persists. :(

Comment: Sorry but it's impossible that the problem could persist, if you implemented that correctly. Check the generated output of your page (by using your browser's View Source feature) and verify that the HTML matches the pattern I've shown above. Show us the generated HTML, if you're unsure.

Comment: I edited the question adding the View Source. I´d appreciate if you take a look.

Comment: @MarcosCarvalho _"I followed the instructions that I received, but did not work"_ ... that's not true. Here's a demo using the HTML you have shown: https://jsfiddle.net/2n5mqcau/ ...the radio buttons work exactly as they should. Whatever is going on in your page, it's not the fault of that HTML or my answer.

Comment: Yes, it really worked. But when I added the CSS, I had the problem. So, it is the CSS the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Ok no problem. You should maybe ask a new question about that CSS specifically as well, if you don't solve it :-)